# Looking for software to create instruction sheets

Tags: windows, office

I want to create 4.25 inch x 6 inch instruction sheets for products I sell. I tried word or photoshop to divide a letter sized page into 2 equal parts with a dotted line but I'm not sure there must be a better software for this.

Answer (score 1):

[Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) sounds like the right product for you.

It is a free and open source vector illustration software, in the same vein as Adobe Illustrator.

If your instructions are single page that is, you can configure a page with the desired paper size, divide it as required and save it as a reusable template.

As of Inkscape 1.2+ creating and editing multi-page documents is now supported.

Assuming your instructions will have pictures and graphical representations of your product you can design them directly in Inkscape as vector objects.

Answer (score 0):

There are free, Free, and non-free programs that do this for multiple platforms, including Windows. You are basically wavering between simple document creation and desktop publishing.

Using Word, Open Office, Google Docs, etc. it is very possible to create a workable set of instructions on a split page just like you are intending. The next step up is to use page layout software - InDesign, Scribus, MS Publisher, etc. and move out of document creation and into desktop publishing.

No matter which software you go with, it may be better to do a single page, and then either set page properties to 2 copies per 11x8.5 or have the print utilities do it as 2 per page.  Create your master, take it to a real print shop (or email PDF - and the PDF part is important), and have them run it off and cut to size in quantity needed.

Comment: Mmm ok I'll take a look. I'm a bit confused on how to actually use them though and set up but I'll try to cehck